# I have set the background-color to white, but how does the opacity of the parent element affect it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

I have set the background color of the inner div to white and the opacity of its parent div to 0.6. It seems that the background color of the inner div is not exactly white. If I change the opacity of the parent div to 1.0, the problem disapears, why?
http://jsbin.com/zekacunefi/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <style>
  #msg_container {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 3800;
   background-color: #000000;
   opacity: 0.6;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }

  #modalDialog {
   display: inline-block;
   z-index: 3801;
   background-color: white;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid rgb(103, 103, 103);
   box-shadow: 0 4px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
  }

  body {
   background-color: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <script>
  MessageBox("abc\ndef\ng\nhdasfasdfsdsdfsd");
  function MessageBox(str) {
   var boxHtml = "<div id='msg_container'><div id='modalDialog'></div></div>";
   $("body").append(boxHtml);
   var md = $("#modalDialog");
   var contentArray = str.split("\n");
   var newArray = contentArray.map(function(ele, idx) {
    return ele + "<br>";
   });
   md.html("<p>" + newArray.join("") + "</p>");
   var w = md.width(),
       h = md.height();
   md.css({
    marginTop: -1 * h / 2 + "px",
    marginLeft: -1 * w / 2 + "px"
   });
   $("#msg_container").appendTo($("body"));
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use "opacity", you're not only setting the opacity of the div background, but also the opacity of the whole content. (see this W3C Wiki as example : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity)

IMHO, you should remove the opacity setting from both #msg_container and #modalDialog and then using instead rgba() to define background color of #msg_container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #msg_container {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 3800;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }

  #modalDialog {
   display: inline-block;
   z-index: 3801;
   background-color: white;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid rgb(103, 103, 103);
   box-shadow: 0 4px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
  }

  body {
   background-color: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <script>
  MessageBox("abc\ndef\ng\nhdasfasdfsdsdfsd");
  function MessageBox(str) {
   var boxHtml = "<div id='msg_container'><div id='modalDialog'></div></div>";
   $("body").append(boxHtml);
   var md = $("#modalDialog");
   var contentArray = str.split("\n");
   var newArray = contentArray.map(function(ele, idx) {
    return ele + "<br>";
   });
   md.html("<p>" + newArray.join("") + "</p>");
   var w = md.width(),
       h = md.height();
   md.css({
    marginTop: -1 * h / 2 + "px",
    marginLeft: -1 * w / 2 + "px"
   });
   $("#msg_container").appendTo($("body"));
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because opacity on parent is affecting inner div too and blue color is body background. Instead what you can do is set `rgba()` for parent div

Try this

```
    #msg_container {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You change the opacity of the parent and all it's children. This means that you will see the blue background through both the parent div and the child.